# Inno Setup - the icon on a desktop is not presented

Tags: installation, icons, inno-setup

I had been project in Inno Setup. All is installed perfectly, but the icon on a desktop is not presented - white color of icon.

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "3.2.0"
#define MyAppVersionName "My Program 3 (64-bit)"
#define MyAppExeName "myprogram.exe"

..................

[Setup]
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\path_to_my_program\myprogram_Icon.ico

................

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppVersionName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

If I had been write section [Icons]:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

then I get icon on desktop perfectly after installed.

How can I solve it problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If the EXE does not containt the Icon integrated, then you should copy/install the Icon File along with the EXE and use `IconFilenName` flag in `[Icons]` section, eg.: `[Files] Source: "C:\Users\path_to_my_program\myprogram_Icon.ico"; DestDir: "{app}" [Icons] Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppVersionName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFileName: "{app}\myprogram_Icon.ico"; Tasks: desktopicon`

Answer (score 1):

If the `EXE` does not have a default application icon, then you should copy/install the `Icon File` along with the `EXE` and use the [`IconFileName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=IconFilename) parameter from `[Icons]` section to specify the path to it:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\path_to_my_program\myprogram_Icon.ico"; DestDir: "{app}" 

[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppVersionName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; 
  IconFileName: "{app}\myprogram_Icon.ico"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Comment: @AndriySkolozhabskiy - you can either Accept the Answer by marking the Check under the Vote Counter or UpVote this answer if it solves your problem :)